# jquery based slideshow plugin issue on safari and opera

Tags: jquery, css, safari, slideshow, opera

I'm using a very good plugin for animation/transitions with css3 based on jquery called [Sequence.js](http://www.sequencejs.com/), and i'm using it for a simple responsive fadeIn-fadeOut slideshow.

With chrome/firefox everything is working fine and smooth as expected, but on **opera** the whole thing is stuck, wile in **safari** something really weird happens:
the animation start with the frame fadingIn, shortly after it disappears, after 5 seconds or so (plugin time to start the next frame animation) the frame reappear to start the fadeOut, the sequent frame fadeIn, and then again the whole thing disappear, over and over.

I can't really tell what's happening, and here is a link with the thing working http://bit.ly/SQV3Xl

How can this be fixed to work like in chrome/firefox or even ie with fallback?

Comment: is the plugin mobile friendly?

Comment: yes it is, or at least on the docs it's stated like that, i've used it couple times before also and it worked quite well, really don't know whats wrong now

Comment: well i guess you can compare this one to the previously setup ones and see if you can spot anything. I usually write my own rotator cuz plugins are usually not good enough. there is a rotator on toyota.ca homepage maybe you can write your own by looking at that one

Comment: That's the first thing i tried, unfortunately nothing was different, or at least anything i was able to see. Also i'm realy a novice (quite a noob to be honest) with javascript, and i like a lot this plugin as it opens lot of implementations with css3 transitions and animations. Can't really tell what's wrong now though.

Comment: do you have a link that i can see where it works properly

Comment: nothing easy to implement and link to, many are projects in local and not yet published, anyway on the plugin's site you can see some good examples. Also i'm curious can you recreate the issue on iphone with the link i posted?

Comment: yea I see the issue, it seems after the image has faded in, it is hidden right away, and when the next fade starts it shows again and it just repeats. So the rotation works it's just the showing after fading is glitched. maybe it's your css hiding it or something... or do you have any media queries that might be hiding the image?

Comment: At least it's not an isolated hardware case! ;)
No media queries screwing, you can see it resizing yourself also on browser, dunno if Twitter Bootstrap put something more maybe only for retina/iphones/mobile or else that its not triggered on normal browsers, i'll investigate more eventually

Comment: strip your page to bare bones and test. take out bootstrap and whatnot then test and add stuff back in one by one so you can see which one is breaking it

Comment: i've updated the question as this is an issue with Safari in general, not only mobile browsers on iphone, and opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, tinkering with the inspector in safari, it seems that he doesn't like to have no `height` specified for the container element `#sequence`, but i really can't understand why.
Odd enough also opera seems to appreciate the `height` specified in the CSS: now when the script loads sometimes works, sometimes wont, and i still can't really get why all this mess..

I'll close the issue as this is "fixed", but i really like to know **WHY** this is happening. Can someone shed some light on this?